# How to cast list element to int and compare it with number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a flat file in txt format seperated by space.

```
ID  Math    Eng Phy
A   70      75  77
B   56      79  80
C   90      89  56
```

I need to compare each number if its less than 70.
What i am doing : I am able to store this file in dictionary but when i am comparing number getting :

```
"if int(m) < 70:ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Math' "
```

error. Below is my code:

```
with open('student.txt','r') as file:
     rows = ( line.split('\t') for line in file )
     d = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
for l in d:
    print(l,d[l])
    for m in d[l]:
        if int(m) < 70:
           print(m)
```

Comment: `m` is not what you appear to think it is. try `print`ing it before the cast to `int`

Comment: try `print(m)` before you try to make it an `int`. You may find that you need to `strip` it of whitespace or something

Comment: You need to exclude your header line.

Comment: Why do you suppose Python might be trying to convert the word "Math" to an integer?

Comment: I suggest you learn how to debug your own code. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems for some tips to get started. Debugging will show that you are attempting to convert the word `"Math"` to an integer value. (As will carefully reading the error message.)

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I am printing it before cast and checking its type(m),its str type. I am suppose to print numbers smaller than 70.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to skip the first line because it is the header:

```
next(rows)
d = { row[0]:row[1:] for row in rows }
```

Btw, `rows` is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) so it is better not to exhaust it for allocating less memory:

```
with open('student.txt','r') as f:
    rows = ( line.split('\t') for line.strip() in f )
    next(rows)

    for l in rows:
        for m in l[1:]:
            if int(m) < 70:
                print(m)
```

Comment: Thank you,but i am getting this error ,TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Thank you, I am using python 3.x. So next(rows) worked for me.

Comment: How do you handle words separated by multiple spaces?  Here you `split(\t)` assuming the file is tab delimited.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake you are doing is that you are including the header in your calculations. Doing that ultimately results in a `int('Math')` which of course fails and raises a `ValueError`. So do this instead:

```
with open('student.txt') as file:
    d = {x: y for x, *y in [row.split() for row in file.split('\n')][1:]}
    for k, v in d.items():
        print('{}\n\t{}'.format(k, '\n'.join([x for x in v if int(x)<70] or '-')))
```

Notice the `[1:]` slicing on the internal list-comprehension.